# Form checkbox and label with CakePHP and Bootstrap

Tags: cakephp, twitter-bootstrap

I'm having some issues trying to get checkbox inputs and labels to output the correct HTML using CakePHP and Twitter Bootstrap.

The Bootstrap specific output should be:

```
<div class="control-group">
  <div class="controls">
    <label class="checkbox">
      <input type="checkbox"> Keep me logged in
    </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

However, using the inputDefaults mentioned here (http://stackoverflow.com/a/9496242/1247225), this Cake form input:

```
echo $form->input('auto_login', array(
 'type' => 'checkbox', 
 'label' => __('Keep me logged in', true)));
```

Outputs this:

```
  <div class="control-group">
    <input type="hidden" name="data[User][auto_login]" id="UserAutoLogin_" value="0" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="data[User][auto_login]" class="" value="1" id="UserAutoLogin" />
    <div class="controls">
      <label for="UserAutoLogin">Keep me logged in</label>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Any ideas how to adjust this individual input so it outputs the correct Bootstrap HTML, like above?

Answer (score 5):

The best way to control the form output, or the format of the output, is by passing a 'format' argument. Try playing with this:

```
'format' => array('before', 'label', 'input', 'between', 'after', 'error')
```

I don't think it is document, but by reading the code, you can find it in there.

Answer (score 4):

the prettiest way to do it is this:

```
<?php
echo '<div class="col-lg-2">';
echo $this->Form->input('Content.checkbox', array(
'div' => array(
    'class' => 'input-group',
),
'label' => false,
'type' => 'checkbox',
'before' => '<span class="input-group-addon">',
'after' => '</span><span class="input-group-addon"><label for="ContentCheckbox">What does the fox say?</label></span>',
));
echo '</div>';
```

Answer (score 3):

I using :

```
<?php 
echo $this->Form->input('coupDeCoeur', 
array('div' => false,
'label' => false,
'type' => 'checkbox',
'before' => '<label class="checkbox">',
'after' => '<i></i>coupDeCoeur</label>'
));
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to build the form widget manually for checkboxes instead of using `FormHelper::input`.

For example:

```
echo '<div class="control-group">';
echo $this->Form->label('Model.field', null, array('class' => 'control-label')); 
echo '<div class="controls">';
echo $this->Form->checkbox('Model.field');
echo '</div>';
echo '</div>';
```

Answer (score 2):

Try following code:

```
<div class="control-group">
    <div class="controls">
        <label class="checkbox">
            <?php echo $this->Form->input('auto_login', array('type'=>'checkbox','label' => false, 'div' => false,'class'=>false,'after'=>__('Keep me logged in')));?>
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using security component, you may have problems if you create your inputs without `FormHelper::input`. If that's the case, you should try with this:

```
echo "
<div class='control-group'>
    <div class='controls'>
        <label class='checkbox'>";                    
            echo $this->Form->input('Model.field', array('label' => false, 'after' => 'Model.field'))."
       </label>
    </div>
</div>";
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the ready-to-use solution:

```
App::uses('FormHelper', 'View/Helper');
class InputHelper extends FormHelper {
    // var $helpers = array('Form', 'Html');
    public function create($model, $options = array()) {
        $options['class'] = (isset($options['class']) && $options['class']) ? $options['class'] : 'form-horizontal table';
        $options['inputDefaults'] = (isset($options['inputDefaults']) && $options['inputDefaults']) ? $options['inputDefaults'] : array(
            'div' => 'control-group',
            'label' => array('class' => 'control-label'),
            'between' => '<div class="controls">',
            'after' => '</div>'
        );
        return parent::create($model, $options);
    }

    public function input($fieldName, $options = array()) {
        $this->setEntity($fieldName);
        $options = $this->_parseOptions($options);
        if ($options['type'] == 'checkbox') {
            $options['format'] = array('before', 'label', 'between', 'input', 'after', 'error');
        }
        fdebug($options);
        return parent::input($fieldName, $options);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want a "one line" answer i got it:

```
echo $this->Form->input('Model.Field', array('class'=>'form-inline', 'after'=>'</br>'));
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I used AdminLTE template with Bootstrap 3 and this code was working for me:

```
       <?php
            echo $this->Form->input('Model.fieldname', array(
                'label' => false,
                'type' => 'checkbox',
                'before' => '<label>',
                'after' => 'Field name label here</label>',
            ));
       ?>
```

Good luck here!!!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple solution that works for me:

The CSS (LESS):

```
input.form-control[type="checkbox"] {
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    margin-right: 5px;
    display: inline;
}
```

Then use the Form helper:

```
echo $this->Form->input(
    'field_name',
    array(
        'div' => 'form-group',
        'class' => 'form-control',
        'type' => 'checkbox',
        'label' => array(
            'text' => 'Your label',
            'class' => 'label-checkbox'
        ),
        'format' => array('input', 'label')
    )
);
```