# What specific files do I need to include like css, javascript

Tags: css, cakephp, bootstrap-4, cakephp-3.0

I downloaded bootstrap4 but I dont know exactly what css or js or other files need to include to make my form boostrap ready.

This is what I need to do now.. a form in cakephp 3

[form in cakephp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31242126/cakephp-formhelper-with-bootstrap-horizontal-form)

[form in cakephp 2](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/21789)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change href/src according to your structure

Ps: I have included Style.css as well which should be your custom CSS and should be placed below bootstrap.css

In head tag

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css">
```

Just before the closing of Body Tag

```
<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Does boostrap.css? will affect all my default css code , My website looks different now

Comment: No it should not unless you are using classes with a similar name. 

Can you share your HTML and CSS?

Comment: I have an idea I will just change the layout in this specific area.. and I will just call the bootsrap in this layout