# is there any way to get value from Bootstrap form in cakephp?

Tags: php, forms, cakephp, twitter-bootstrap-3, cakephp-2.x

I don't want to use FormHelper which is avaiable in Cakephp, So i try to use normal Bootstrap form like this:

```
    <form action="" class="form-horizontal" role="form" enctype="multipart/form-data">

                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="title" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Product Name</label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="title" name="data[Flower][title]" placeholder="Product Name">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
 </form>
```

In AddFunction in Controller:

```
public function add() {
    pr($this->request->data('data[Flower][category_id]'));
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {

        $this->Flower->set(array(
            'title' => $this->request->data('data[Flower][title]'),
        ));
        $this->Flower->save();
```

}

But it doesn't work. Help me :(

Updated: I found a source which solved my problem, but i have to stick with FormHelper (but now it's much more comfortable):

[Using CakePHP FormHelper with Bootstrap Forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9495951/using-cakephp-formhelper-with-bootstrap-forms)

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this code:

`public function add() {
        pr($this->request->data('Flower.category_id'));
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            $this->Flower->set(array(
                'title' => $this->request->data('Flower.title'),
            ));
            $this->Flower->save();
    }`

$_POST['data'] is an array, so you must use it as one.

@EDIT: thanks to @ndm for teach me about the data method, look at the link in the comments

Comment: That won't work too, there will be no `data` key in the CakePHP request object anymore. Recommended usage would be `request->data('Flower.category_id')`. **https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers/request-response.html#accessing-post-data**

Comment: Thanks for the Info, I didn't read the documentation completely. But you can still access the data property?

Comment: sorry, but "Notice (8): Undefined index: Flower [APP\Controller\FlowersController.php, line 54]" :))

Comment: whats happend if you use `print_r` on `$this->request->data` ? With the output you can easily check the array format

Comment: @Sysix You can access the `$data` property too, yes, but the method usage is more safe, as it won't error out on missing keys, but instead return `null`, which in turn can then for example be catched by validation rules.